# How to get hours from JodaTime with timezone

Tags: android, datetime, intellij-idea, android-studio, jodatime

I encounter strange behaviour with Jodatime and Android. I want to parse string:

```
2014-05-19T18:13:00.000+02:00
```

to DateTime, and get year, month, hours to int. I started with some test on IntelliJ Studio, and I done something like that:

```
String date = "2014-05-19T18:13:00.000+02:00";
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date);
System.out.println(dateTime.toString());
System.out.println(dateTime.getYear());
System.out.println(dateTime.getMonthOfYear());
System.out.println(dateTime.getDayOfMonth());
System.out.println(dateTime.getHourOfDay());
System.out.println(dateTime.getMinuteOfHour());
System.out.println(dateTime.getMillis());
```

Which gave me correct answers:

```
2014-05-19T18:13:00.000+02:00
2014
5
19
18
13
1400515980000
```

Now, when I changed IDE to Android Studio, and do the same:

```
String dateT = "2014-05-19T18:13:00.000+02:00";
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(dateT);
Lo.g(dateTime.getHourOfDay() + "");
Lo.g(dateTime.toString());
```

my results are:

```
16
2014-05-19T16:13:00.000Z
```

For some reason DateTime on Android Studio / Android not take into account the timezone which is +2:00.

I can not find solution for this. Also there is no simple method "addTimeZone" in Joda.

How to display correct time with DataTime? I tried LocalDateTime, construct DateTime with DateTimeZone.getDefault() (which gaves me UTF...)

Comment: OK, I've got correct value with DateTimeFormatter, but still I do not know what does this difference.

Comment: Have you verified that you have the same Joda-Time-version on both platforms?

Comment: Yes, I've using the newest version on both platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said that you use the same Joda-Time version on both platforms and regarding the fact that Joda-Time has its own timezone repository independent from system timezone data, there is probably only one explanation left why you observe different behaviour: **Different input either explicit or implicit**. Let's go into details:

Well, you say, obviously there is the same input given the same input string:

"2014-05-19T18:13:00.000+02:00"

So we have the same (explicit) input. But wait, there is another thing: **implicit default settings** which can also be considered as kind of input in an abstract way. You use the constructor `DateTime(Object)`. This constructor first delegates to super constructor of class `BaseDateTime` as you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/master/src/main/java/org/joda/time/DateTime.java).

```
public DateTime(Object instant) {        
  super(instant, (Chronology) null);    
}
```

The [javadoc](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/BaseDateTime.html#BaseDateTime%28java.lang.Object,%20org.joda.time.Chronology%29) of this super-constructor says:

> "Constructs an instance from an Object that represents a datetime,
>   using the specified chronology.  If the chronology is null, ISO in the
>   default time zone is used.
>
> The recognised object types are defined in ConverterManager and
>   include ReadableInstant, String, Calendar and Date."

So finally we see that Joda-Time uses the default timezone. This is really the only possibility for different behaviour I can see by studying the source code and the documentation. All other things are equal: Same library version and same explicit string input and same test scenario.

Conclusion: **You have different default timezones on your platforms.** Note that you get **the same instant** on both platforms however, just represented with different local timestamps and offsets due to different internal timezone/offset setting inside the `DateTime`-object.

**Update:** I have tested the zone overriding behaviour with this code:

```
String date = "2014-05-19T19:13:00.000+03:00"; // same instant as yours (just with offset +03)
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date);
System.out.println(dateTime.toString());
// output: 2014-05-19T18:13:00.000+02:00 (in my default timezone Europe/Berlin)
```

So the default timezone has precedence over any offset in string input. If you instead want to use the parsed offset then look at using the [DateTimeFormatter](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withOffsetParsed%28%29) and its method `withOffsetParsed()`.

Comment: It's a good, well documented answer. Thanks for that. I've tested DateTimeZone.getDefault() method on both platforms, which gaves me different timezones (Android Studio + Genymotion -> UTC, IntelliJ Studio -> my correct timezone - Europe/Warsaw). And I solved this by DateTimeFormatter as you said.

Comment: @Bresiu Glad to help you. Personally I dislike implicit settings or defaults because it can easily be overlooked.